# List(T) RemoveAll() not working as intended...?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Let's say I have a list of User objects with two properties...ID and Name

```
List<User> lst = List<User>();
```

I fill it up with a bunch of Users.  Ok, now I want to trim my list using RemoveAll() and this function.

```
private Boolean IsExisting(int id) {
//blah blah
return true;
//blah blah
return false;
}
```

So I use this statement:

```
gdvFoo.DataSource = lst.RemoveAll(t => IsExisting(t.ID));
```

It is my understanding that whenever IsExisting returns true that element should be removed from lst, but what happens, strangely enough, is it returns an integer?, not a truncated list and I received the following error message:

> Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.>

Comment: You could try reading the documentation for RemoveAll http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx which clearly explains what it returns and has examples of how to use it.

Comment: I noted and read the documentation twice.  That is why I asked on here, because I couldn't figure out how mine was differing from their example...but I suppose that's what I get for trying to be too clever and jack too much into one line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RemoveAll() returns the number of elements removed.
You need to do this:

```
lst.RemoveAll(t => IsExisting(t.ID)); 
gdvFoo.DataSource = lst;
```

Answer (score 7):

[List.RemoveAll method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)

The method removes all matching instances from the list on which you called it. This modifies the existing list, rather than returning a new one.

The return value is the number of rows removed.

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) are very clear about what's going on:

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The number of elements removed from the List .

Perhaps the following Linq would be more in line with your expectations?

```
lst.Except(t => IsExisting(t.ID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of RemoveAll(), you could try using IEnumerable's filter where you would say something like :

```
var filteredList = lst.Where(item => IsExisting(item.Id))
```

This makes the code a little more easier to read and focusses on the objective of the task at hand, rather than how to look at implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>.RemoveAll(...)` has a return type of `int` which is not an `IListSource`, `IEnumerable` nor `IDataSource`

Answer (score 1):

The RemoveAll is modifying the list and returning the number of items removed.  You just set your datasource to the list in a second step.

```
lst.RemoveAll(t => IsExisting(t.ID));
gdvFoo.DataSource = lst;
```